# d3 append simple area

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts

I want to append simple area to my chart with end points of area values as constants.

```
percentArea = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate('linear')
      .x0(0)
      .x1(w)
      .y0(h/4)
      .y1(h);
```

I want to append this area directly and give it a color fill. Thanks for help. I am having specially hard time trying to get the area fill. The chart shows a line over the area but no fill when I tried.

Edit: Trying to make the question more clear and specific : The issue I face is only when I try to call my function without passing data. The area fill works as expected when I call percentArea(data). However I am unable to understand why I must pass data when endpoints of my area are constant.

Comment: I do not wish to call this as percentArea(data) as endpoints are fixed so passing data seems wrong.

Comment: `.style("fill", colour)`

Comment: Yes thanks that works when I used  append("path").attr("d",percentArea(data)) .style("fill",color). Any suggestion please to improve the way I call this? Or is this the only way even if endpoints are constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the path you have rendered is being filled. There are two ways you can do this:

**Set a Style**

```
path.style("fill", "steelblue");
```

**Set a class and leverage CSS**

```
path.attr("class", "filled-area");

// In CSS
.filled-area {
    fill: steelblue;
}
```

Here's a quick example:

**Area Chart with a Stroke:**

[image: Area Chart with a Stroke]

**Area Chart with no fill**

As you can see this defaults to black

[image: Area Chart with no fill]

**Area Chart with correct fill**

[image: Area Chart with correct fill]

Comment: My question has been slightly misinterpreted . However you have answered accordingly so thanks. I have problem with area-fill when I try to append the area to svg without passing it any data. The way you suggest works when I call my area function as percentArea(data). However I do not understand why I must pass data even when my end points are constant.

Comment: @hunters30: Tell you what - ask another question with an example that I can run (put a link as a comment in this question), and I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok made a new question and tried to be more specific. Also adding a fiddle to show my problem in it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572800/d3-append-a-svg-with-constant-area)