# d3 append a svg with constant area

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a svg element to which I want to append an area whose end-points are constant/calculated already. Now If I call this area by passing data to it and then plotting it as function over x-axis it works fine and I also see the color filled-area. However if I mark all end points eg: x0,x1,y0,y1 then the area does not show or doesnt fill color. Is it possible to append constant area to svg and if yes then how? The previous question was deviating so I was asked to make a new question which is specific.[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554055/d3-append-simple-area/32572142?noredirect=1#comment53000016_32572142)

Created a fiddle here to show my problem : [Problem](https://jsfiddle.net/f8qwao3e/1/)

```
var percentArea = d3.svg.area()
// do not want to use this    .x(function(d){return x(d.date);})
                    .x0(0)
                    .x1(width)
                    .y0(0)
                    .y1(height);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class","area")
    .attr("d",percentArea);
```

Note if possible i do not want to pass data by setting datum here as end points are constant.

Comment: OK, I think maybe you've mis-understood how `d3.svg.area()` works. `x0()` and `x1()` are accessors for different series - which you're not using. The same is true for `y0()` and `y1()`. What are you ultimately wanting to draw? Just a large rectangle?

Comment: Well if you put it like that then yes. I have a fixed range I want to put as green area in my graph from start of x-Axis till its end. Should I not be drawing an area at all rather a rectangle?

Comment: I'd consider drawing a rectangle instead to be honest. Let me try updating your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use the `d3.svg.area()` path generator for what you're trying to do. If all you want is a background fill you should be able to do that with a simple rectangle. Here's my attempt from your fiddle:

```
svg.append("rect")
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .style("fill", "orange");
```

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var percentArea = d3.svg.area()
// do not want to use this    .x(function(d){return x(d.date);})
     .x0(0)
     .x1(width)
     .y0(0)
     .y1(height);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
 
    data = [
  {
    "date":"1-May-12",
    "close":582.13
  },
  {
    "date":"30-Apr-12",
    "close":583.98
  },
  {
    "date":"27-Apr-12",
    "close":603
  },
  {
    "date":"26-Apr-12",
    "close":607.7
  },
  {
    "date":"25-Apr-12",
    "close":610
  },
  {
    "date":"24-Apr-12",
    "close":560.28
  },
  {
    "date":"23-Apr-12",
    "close":571.7
  },
  {
    "date":"20-Apr-12",
    "close":572.98
  },
  {
    "date":"19-Apr-12",
    "close":587.44
  },
  {
    "date":"18-Apr-12",
    "close":608.34
  },
  {
    "date":"17-Apr-12",
    "close":609.7
  },
  {
    "date":"16-Apr-12",
    "close":580.13
  },
  {
    "date":"13-Apr-12",
    "close":605.23
  },
  {
    "date":"12-Apr-12",
    "close":622.77
  }
];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  //svg.append("path")
  //    .datum(data)
   //   .attr("class", "area")
    ///  .attr("d", area);
  
 svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "orange");
    
    //THIS PART MAKES AREA OF CONSTANT SIZE BUT NEED TO PASS DATA TO IT.   
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class","area")
    .attr("d",percentArea);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="plotgraph"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that looks exactly like what I was trying to set ! Thanks for correcting my wrong usage.